# SSIS Generate XML from Schema and Excel

Tags: xml, ssis

I have an excel file with Order details. I can grab this file in SSIS no issue.

I need to convert the variables in this file into a XML file (Basda's Standard slimmed down)

Most of the header info of the xml will be static

This is new to me and from what i've read i need to create a schema. but how are the values inserted? if an order has 2 lines the task will need to be repeated into the same xml - orders must be separate files

A suggestion I saw which made sense was to get the data into a sql table and to use a query(for xml) as part of the data flow. - is this the best solution?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order>
  <OrderHead>
    <Schema>
      <Version>3.0</Version>
    </Schema>
    <Stylesheet>
      <StylesheetOwner>BASDA</StylesheetOwner>
      <StylesheetName>eBIS-XML_simplestylesheet_schema3.00.xsl</StylesheetName>
      <Version>3</Version>
      <StylesheetType>XSL</StylesheetType>
    </Stylesheet>
    <Parameters>
      <Language>EN_GB</Language>
      <DecimalSeparator>.</DecimalSeparator>
      <Precision>20.3</Precision>
    </Parameters>
    <TestFlag />
    <OrderType Code="PUO">Purchase Order</OrderType>
    <OrderCurrency>
      <Currency Code="GBP">GBP</Currency>
    </OrderCurrency>
    <Checksum />
  </OrderHead>
  <OrderReferences>
    <CostCentre />
    <BuyersOrderNumber Preserve="true"></BuyersOrderNumber>
    <SuppliersOrderNumber Preserve="true"></SuppliersOrderNumber>
    <ProjectCode Preserve="true" />
    <ProjectAnalysisCode Preserve="true" />
  </OrderReferences>
  <OrderDate></OrderDate>
  <Supplier>
    <SupplierReferences>
      <BuyersCodeForSupplier></BuyersCodeForSupplier>
    </SupplierReferences>
    <Party></Party>
    <Address>
        <AddressLine></AddressLine>
        <AddressLine></AddressLine>
    <AddressLine></AddressLine>
      <City></City>
      <State></State>
      <PostCode></PostCode>
    </Address>
    <Contact>
      <Name />
      <Switchboard />
      <Fax />
      <Email />
    </Contact>
  </Supplier>
  <Buyer>
    <BuyerReferences>
      <SuppliersCodeForBuyer></SuppliersCodeForBuyer>
      <GLN></GLN>
    </BuyerReferences>
    <Party></Party>
    <BuyersOwnCompanyCode />
    <Address>
      <AddressLine></AddressLine>
      <Street></Street>
      <City></City>
      <State></State>
      <PostCode></PostCode>
    </Address>
    <Contact>
      <Name></Name>
      <Department />
      <DDI />
      <Switchboard />
      <Fax />
      <Email />
    </Contact>
  </Buyer>
  <Delivery>
    <Carrier>
      <Party />
    </Carrier>
    <DeliverTo>
      <DeliveryReferences>
        <BuyersCodeForDelivery></BuyersCodeForDelivery>
        <GLN></GLN>
        <BuyersCodeForLocation></BuyersCodeForLocation>
      </DeliveryReferences>
      <Party></Party>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine></AddressLine>
        <AddressLine></AddressLine>
    <AddressLine></AddressLine>
        <City></City>
        <State></State>
        <PostCode>G</PostCode>
      </Address>
      <Contact>
        <Name />
        <Switchboard />
        <Fax />
      </Contact>
    </DeliverTo>
    <PreferredDate></PreferredDate>
  </Delivery>
  <InvoiceTo>
    <Party></Party>
    <Address>
        <AddressLine></AddressLine>
        <AddressLine>Ct</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine></AddressLine>
      <City></City>
      <State></State>
      <PostCode></PostCode>
    </Address>
    <Contact>
      <Name />
      <Department />
      <DDI />
      <Switchboard />
      <Fax />
      <Email />
    </Contact>
  </InvoiceTo>
 <Settlement>
        <CardDetails>
            <Issuer>Visa</Issuer>
            <Address>
                <HouseNumber />
                <PostCode />
            </Address>
            <ValidFrom>
            </ValidFrom>
            <ExpiresEnd></ExpiresEnd>
            <IssueNumber/>
            <CardNumber></CardNumber>
            <AuthorisationCode>
            </AuthorisationCode>
        </CardDetails>
    </Settlement>
  <OrderLine Action="Add">
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <Delivery>
      <DeliverTo>
        <DeliverToReferences>
          <BuyersCodeForDelivery></BuyersCodeForDelivery>
          <BuyersCodeForLocation></BuyersCodeForLocation>
        </DeliverToReferences>
        <Party></Party> 
        <Address>
          <AddressLine></AddressLine>
          <Street></Street>
          <City></City>
          <State></State>
          <PostCode></PostCode>
          <Contact>
            <Name />
            <Switchboard />
            <Fax />
            <Email />
          </Contact>
        </Address>
      </DeliverTo>
    </Delivery>
    <OrderLineReferences>
      <BuyersOrderNumber Preserve="true"></BuyersOrderNumber>
      <ProjectCode Preserve="true" />
      <ProjectAnalysisCode Preserve="true" />
    </OrderLineReferences>
    <Product>
      <BuyersProductCode></BuyersProductCode>
      <SuppliersProductCode></SuppliersProductCode>
      <Description></Description>
    </Product>
    <Quantity UOMCode="EA" UOMDescription="Each">
      <Amount></Amount>
    </Quantity>
    <Price UOMCode="EA" UOMDescription="Each">
      <Units>1</Units>
      <UnitPrice></UnitPrice>
    </Price>
    <PercentDiscount>
      <Percentage></Percentage>
    </PercentDiscount>
    <LineTotal></LineTotal>
    <PreferredDate></PreferredDate>
    <OrderLineInformation>
      <OriginalOrderLineNumber></OriginalOrderLineNumber>
      <DistributionMethod></DistributionMethod>
    </OrderLineInformation>
  </OrderLine>
</Order>
```

Comment: The are many was of generating xml and the methods depends on the programming language. You have a complicated xml file and SQL Server is not the best programming tool to use to generate xml.  Since you have excel it may be best to use vba to do the work.  My preference is to use c# to read/write xml.  Using a schema is not always required, but I believe if you are doing it in SSIS it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, it should be two step process.

(1) Load data from Excel into SQL Server staging table(s).

(2) Craft a `SELECT ... FOR XML ..` statement to generate desired XML.